# Returning only whole numbers in MS Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I know this might be a simple one but for the life of me I cant get it to work.

I have the below query:

```
SELECT 
[1_Data_Set].EAN_CODE, 
[1_Data_Set].CPFUSER_CONSUMER_UNIT_DESCRIPTION, 
[1_Data_Set].CASE_WIDTH, 
[1_Data_Set].CASE_HEIGHT, 
[1_Data_Set].CASE_LENGTH, 
[1_Data_Set].CPFUSER_CONSUMER_UNIT_INTRODUCED_DATE, 
[1_Data_Set].WAREHOUSED_IND INTO DEFAULTS
FROM 1_Data_Set

WHERE 

([1_Data_Set].CASE_WIDTH =[1_Data_Set].CASE_HEIGHT  
AND
[1_Data_Set].CASE_HEIGHT  = [1_Data_Set].CASE_LENGTH
AND
[1_Data_Set].CASE_LENGTH = [1_Data_Set].CASE_WIDTH);
```

I want to return the values where the width, length and height all match (there maybe a more logical way than the one I have entered above)

AND

Only whole numbers, I cannot use the INT() command to display whole numbers, I want ot reurn only whole numbers

Currently being returned example:

```
EAN       Height      Width     Length
58554       10          10        10
85965       11.1        11.1      11.1
```

Required:

```
EAN       Height      Width     Length
58554       10          10        10
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: I have added both examples of current and required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this does what you want:

```
select *
from l_data_set
where height = round(height, 0) and width = round(width, 0) and
      length = round(length, 0) and
      height = width and width = length;
```

`round()` is safer than `int` because of the way that floating point numbers are stored.

Comment: Thanks, it works by adding the height = round(height, 0) and width = round(width, 0) and
      length = round(length, 0); after my current WHERE clause

Comment: Oh dang.  It looks like I was way late to the party.

Comment: Think that answer may need updating - it will return if the three values are integers and different from each other.  i.e. Height = 1, Width = 2 and Length = 3 would be a valid record.  Maybe `height = round(height,0) and width = round(height, 0) and length = round(height,0)`

Comment: You can safely use `Int()` but it rounds down while `Round()` performs midway rounding to even.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the base number is equal to the INT of the base number

```
SELECT  *
FROM    1_Data_Set
WHERE   CASE_WIDTH = INT(CASE_WIDTH) AND
        CASE_WIDTH = CASE_HEIGHT AND
        CASE_HEIGHT = CASE_LENGTH
```

Before I post this - is basically the same as Jason Boyds answer.  i.e. just check that the number is an integer first.

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing the query in Access then I think this will do what you need:

```
SELECT 
    [1_Data_Set].EAN_CODE, 
    [1_Data_Set].CPFUSER_CONSUMER_UNIT_DESCRIPTION, 
    [1_Data_Set].CASE_WIDTH, 
    [1_Data_Set].CASE_HEIGHT, 
    [1_Data_Set].CASE_LENGTH, 
    [1_Data_Set].CPFUSER_CONSUMER_UNIT_INTRODUCED_DATE, 
    [1_Data_Set].WAREHOUSED_IND INTO DEFAULTS
FROM 1_Data_Set
WHERE 
    INT(CASE_WIDTH) - CASE_WIDTH = 0
    AND [1_Data_Set].CASE_WIDTH =[1_Data_Set].CASE_HEIGHT  
    AND [1_Data_Set].CASE_HEIGHT  = [1_Data_Set].CASE_LENGTH
```

The third equality check - `[1_Data_Set].CASE_LENGTH = [1_Data_Set].CASE_WIDTH` - is not necessary because of the transitive property of equality.

If you are executing the query on the SQL side then you could do `CASE_WIDTH % 1 = 0` instead of `INT(CASE_WIDTH) - CASE_WIDTH = 0`